# use servername for remote connection through opnevpn instead of IP address

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, remmina

I'm on Linux `(Ubuntu 20.04)` and I make vpn connection using `openvpn` to my workstation which is windows 10 (I use RDP connection through `remmina`) when I use my workstation IP address I'm able to ping and connect but when I use my workstation name (ex: wks-eshirvana) I'm able ping my workstaion name but remmina doesn't recognize it and I get error message:

> Could not find the address for RDP server "wks-eshirvana"

(note: I'm able to use machinename when I'm on windows)

is there a workaround to use my workstation machine name instead of ip address?

---

**update:**

the error I get is :

> [09:58:00:867] [12184:12296] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_tcp_is_hostname_resolvable:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_DNS_NAME_NOT_FOUND [0x00020005]

I created a bug in [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2430#note_523257706), I paste the answer from remmina developers, It didn't work fro me but might work for someone else:

This is the error raised by the FreeRDP library, and it happens, most probably, because of a confinement issue.
FreeRDP uses getaddrinfo to obtain the hostname IP address.
Unfortunately I don't know how to help you as I have a VPN (OpenConnect) and it works perfectly even with the Snap package.

Try to remove (backup your profiles before) remmina and reinstall with:

```
 sudo snap install remmina --devmode
```

It should install remmina without any restrictions, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Maybe there is some problem on DNS resolution. You can have a try to add a entry pointing your workstation name to the IP address in the hosts file to see if you can use the name for connection.

Comment: @seven but how about when it has dynamic up address that changes? In windows , Remote Desktop uses machine names and its fine , in Linux it should be the same

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup, linux-vpn-windowsmachine. No workaround should be needed, must be something simple. Start with `nmcli` command to see if there is a nameserver on the vpn connection. Mine looks like this:

```
VPN myvpnname VPN connection
        master wlp59s0, VPN, ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.0.211/24
        route4 172.16.1.0/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 192.168.0.0/24
...
DNS configuration:
        servers: 192.168.0.231 192.168.0.244
        domains: vpnxxx.mydomainxxx.com
        interface: tap0
        type: vpn
```

Comment: thank you I see my vpn connection adn I see it in my DNS configuration , however remmina still can't connect  ( see my updated question ) thanks

Comment: I just tested I was ablae to connect using freeeRDP , so it should be something with remmina

Comment: OK great - I am using remmina myself, so it should be workable if you ever need it in the future

Comment: well, its not for me for some reason, I even created a bug in [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2430#note_523377938), and seems like there is something  even developers can't find out how to solve

Comment: Alright that won't be simple as I first claimed. in case it helps with the bug report i have ubuntu 19.10, remmina 1.3.4, and openvpn 2.4.7-1ubuntu2